# MySQL 8.0 Index condition pushdown (ICP) does not take effect

Tags: mysql

Recently I have considered how Index condition Pushdown work, and whether make a difference of locking in Repeatable read isolation level.

However, I find ICP does not take effect in MySQL 8.0, but work in 5.7. The repro steps as below shown ( based on guide in [Index Condition Pushdown Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html)

1. Prepare table and data

```sql
CREATE TABLE `fruit` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `age` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` varchar(16) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `i_age_name` (`age`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


-- Prepare data
delimiter ;;
    CREATE PROCEDURE `load_data`()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE i int DEFAULT 1;
        WHILE i < 300 DO
            INSERT INTO fruit (`name`, `age`, `data`) VALUES 
            (substring(MD5(RAND()),1,20), i / 10 + 1, 'test data'),
            (substring(MD5(RAND()),1,20), i / 10 + 1, 'hello world');
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END ;;
delimiter ;

call load_data();
```

2. execute a query

> explain select * from fruit where age = 10 and name like '%a';

We hope it **Extra** column could show `Using index condition`, but not found, I do not know why?

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fruit | NULL       | ref  | i_age_name    | i_age_name | 5       | const |   20 |    11.11 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

In Mysql 5.7, the query execution plan shows ICP is used

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fruit | NULL       | ref  | i_age_name    | i_age_name | 5       | const |   20 |    11.11 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Are you aware that only `age` of `i_age_name` cab be used since you're using `LIKE` with a wildcard at the *beginning* on `name`?

Comment: With ICP, the condition part of `name` should be also push to Engine right?

Comment: *We hope it Extra column could show Using index condition, but not found, I do not know why?* Depends on data statistic. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=988d48cbc605d408366758c122c8e5f5 - I see "Using index condition"

Comment: @Akina  I tried in db fiddler, it shows "Using index condition". This makes me confusing, why it does not show  in my local side.

Comment: Use this to see if 8.0 it touching more rows:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts